# Android: reorder views by tag inside linearlayout

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout dynamically created, each view inside it have a tag which represents the order I want (1,2,5,4,3).
I need to reoder the views depending of this tag.
How can I do it ?

I've tried this but it does not work :

```
int childcount = dimensioni.getChildCount();
for (int j=0; j < childcount; j++){
    View v = dimensioni.getChildAt(j);
    Log.e("TAG",v.getTag().toString());
}
```

Comment: The posted code fragement simply prints our the dimensioni order. Did you sort it beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

What if you add the children you found to an array of views. Then remove the views from your "dimensioni" and then add them in the correct order via the array of views.